# C# WPF most simplified CollectionChanged event with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, events, data-binding, observablecollection

After much research, I am stumped as to how to implement a *simple* CollectionChanged event. My current set-up uses INotifyPropertyChanged implemented as follows:

```
public class Invasion : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Each Property calls NotifyPropertyChanged like this:

```
public int myProperty
    {
        get { return _backingMember; }
        set { _backingMember = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
```

It all works great. Except:
I need to raise events when a ObservableCollection changes, not just the properties. The trick is, I need this to be super simple; I don't care what got .Add'ed or .Remove'd, I don't care which element was modified, or how, and I don't care if more than one thing changed in a given collection. All I need to know is *if* the collection was changed. That's it.

So I'm looking for a super simple way to implement a CollectionChanged event of some sort. As I mentioned, I've been looking into "INotifyCollectionChanged", but everything I've found on it online has been very complicated with lots of custom handling and whatnot. I don't need all that, and would prefer not to clutter up my code unnecessarily if at all possible.

As of right now I have the following (non-working) code:

```
public class Invasion : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

private void NotifyCollectionChanged(/*Need this code*/)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(/* And this Code */));
        }
    }
```

The collections and their properties are set up like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<FearCard> _fearDeck = new ObservableCollection<FearCard>();
private ObservableCollection<EventCard> _eventDeck = new ObservableCollection<EventCard>();
etc...

...
public ObservableCollection<FearCard> FearDeck
    {
        get { return _fearDeck; }
        set {
                _fearDeck = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TopFearCard");
                NotifyCollectionChanged();
            }
    }
etc...
```

Again, if at all possible I would like to keep this as simple as possible. All I need this to do is notify when my collection changes so that the xaml databinding will update an image when it's changed.

Answer (score 0):

You may probably just pass CollectionChanged event subscription to the `_fearDeck` member (if its the only member collection that should fire the "outer" CollectionChanged event).

```
public class Invasion : INotifyCollectionChanged
{
   private ObservableCollection<FearCard> _fearDeck = new ObservableCollection<FearCard>();

   public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged
   {
       add { _fearDeck.CollectionChanged += value; }
       remove { _fearDeck.CollectionChanged -= value; }
   }

   ...
}
```

Otherwise take a look at the overload list of the [`NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.notifycollectionchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor to get an idea how to implement it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have several collections/members that will each be changing, so i need to have this be able to be somewhat generic as it might be the _fearDeck collection that is changing, or the _blightDeck, or the _eventDeck, etc.

Comment: Ok, that's why I added the last sentence.

Comment: Yea, i've been staring at that page for the last 2 hours.. I think I'm just too new to understand MSDN yet. Every time I end up on their 'help' pages, I end up more confused that when I started. I'll keep re-reading it until it sinks in I guess.

Comment: You may perhaps always just fire the event with the Reset action, with [this NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653204(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the simplest way is to create your observable once and then use it ( .Clear () / .Add ( ... ) / Remove ( ... ) ).
You can then just suscribe directly to the CollectionChanged Event of the observable.

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    void SomeMethod ( )
    {
        Obs.Add ( "item" );

        Obs.Clear ( );
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Obs { get; } 
     = new ObservableCollection<string> ( );

    public ObservableCollection<string> Obs2 { get; }
     = new ObservableCollection<string> ( );
}

class SomeParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public SomeParentViewModel ( )
    {
        Child.Obs.CollectionChanged += ( sender, e ) => { /* Handles collection changed logic */ };

        Child.Obs2.CollectionChanged += ( sender, e ) => { /* Handles collection changed logic */ };
    }

    public SomeViewModel Child { get; }
     = new SomeViewModel ( );
}
```

You could then implement the INotifyCollectionChanged directly on the viewmodel and bubble up the observable collection changed event:

```
class SomeViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    public SomeViewModel ( )
    {
        Obs.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => CollectionChanged?.Invoke ( this, e ); // *edit*
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Obs { get; } 
     = new ObservableCollection<string> ( );
}
```

EDIT:

Since you only need to display a picture when the collection change, there's another approach that could work, a DependencyObject:

```
class DisplayOnNotify : DependencyObject
{
    public static INotifyCollectionChanged GetObservable ( DependencyObject obj )
    {
        return (INotifyCollectionChanged)obj.GetValue ( ObservableProperty );
    }

    public static void SetObservable ( DependencyObject obj, INotifyCollectionChanged value )
    {
        obj.SetValue ( ObservableProperty, value );
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Observable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ObservableProperty =
                           DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached ( "Observable", 
                                                                typeof ( INotifyCollectionChanged ), 
                                                                typeof ( DisplayOnNotify ), 
                                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata ( propertyChangedCallback ) );

    private static void propertyChangedCallback ( DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e )
    {
        if ( d is UIElement uiElement && e.NewValue is INotifyCollectionChanged notify )
        {
            notify.CollectionChanged += ( sender, e_ ) => uiElement.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it directly in xaml:

```
<Image Visibility="Collapsed" local:DisplayOnNotify.Observable="{Binding FearDeck}" />
```

This will effectively display your image on the first collection changed event

Comment: Well, my bad. Have you tried encapsulating an ObservableCollection ?

Comment: Try yourself if adding an element to Obs fires the CollectionChanged event of your SomeViewModel class.

Comment: Ahah, exact, I made a little mistake in the event chaining, It should be Obs.CollectionChanged += (sender, e) => CollectionChanged?.Invoke ( this, e );

Comment: That looks better, except that it might make more sense to pass `Obs` instead of `this` as first argument to Invoke. At least it's Obs that changed (but is not the actual sender of the event). It's questionable, but might be what OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

A collectionchanged event isn't just going to change a picture by itself.
The simplest way I can think of would be to bind the image to an imagesource property exposed from the same viewmodel.
You would then just set that property in the setter and have that raise property changed.

```
set {
        _fearDeck = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
        NotifyPropertyChanged("TopFearCard");
        NotifyPropertyChanged("NameofProperyExposingImageSource");
    }
```

Looking at what you seem to be doing.
I guess maybe this image is exposed from the "top" fear card.
It seems unlikely you're trying to change all pictures in a deck.

Say your "top" car is at index 0 in the collection.  You could bind ImageSource of your image control to whatever property is the picture in FearCard by index. 
ICollectionChanged ( that observablecollection implements ) can notify that one of the objects has changed. The way to force that is to set an object in the observablecollection to itself.
So if TopFearCard is a property pointing to one of the FearCards you could do something like:

```
FearCard[0] = FearCard[0];
```

Comment: Almost everything you said I have already got going - good insight! but ... "ICollectionChanged ( that observablecollection implements ) can notify that one of the objects has changed." that is where my problem is^. I can't seem to figure out how to capture the collectionchanged event correctly. My problem is not 'getting the event to fire', my problem is 'notifying when it has been fired'.

Comment: I don't follow why you need to worry about notifying when it's been fired. You want to change the picture shown? It's in FearCard? If you bind to a property of FearCard and set that instance of the object to itself then the ui will get the property and your picture will change. I thought that was what your problem was.

Comment: So every time I ".add" or ".remove" a card from the fearDeck, fearEarnedDeck, or fearDiscard, I have to also set said deck = itself? That seems odd/redundant. Every time i add or remove something from/to a deck it is supposedly already firing the collectionchanged event, but the picture isn't updating. So you're saying that by adding an *additional* collectionchanged event, it should fix it ? I'm confused.

Comment: Collection changed tells the ui an object was added, removed or changed in the observablecollection. What exactly are you binding to what in order to show this picture and under what specific circumstances do you want it to change?

Comment: I have an Image (on the main window's grid) that has its source bound to the property TopFearCard, which returns fearDeck[0].Source. fearDeck is a collection of FearCard : Card : Image objects. Any time a card is removed via fearDeck.RemoveAt(0), this image *should* update because the top card of the deck, and hence the collection, changed. But it doesn't. Also, thank you very much for all this help/clarification. You rock!